# Can OpenCollada export cgfx shaders from Max?

Tags: collada

We are using the OpenCollada plugin for Max 2011. Geometry and animation data is coming through fine but I don't see any shader or material data included in the DAE.

Do I need to modify the Max exporter or should it just work out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MaxScript we can iterate through the materials and export the cgfx (or directx shaders) to a separate file. Exporting it as part of the Collada is possible if we write a Collada exporter and insert the shader params as extra data. We're going the MaxScript route.

**Update/Edit:** wow, were we wrong about using MaxScript! The correct solution was to use the Max SDK and the IGame interface to query the materials.  Yannick Puech has the definitive [article](http://ypuechweb.free.fr/Files/Using_DirectX_Shaders_in_3ds_Max.pdf).